# The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly on Windows Server 2012 R2 with php 7.0.9 x64

Tags: php

I am getting this issue with when I'm trying to host a PHP website on on IIS.

IIS 8.5 (Server 2012 R2) and PHP 7.0.9

When I switch version to PHP 5.3, it works fine. But PHP 7 gives this error.

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Detailed Error Information:

```
Module     FastCgiModule 
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    PHP_via_FastCGI
Error Code     0xc0000135 
Requested URL      http://localhost/index.php
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

---

A few other links told me that I'm missing VC++ redistributable 2015, so I tried to install that too but it also failed to install anf gave me following error :

```
error code : 0x80240017
Log:

[079C:029C][2016-09-12T01:41:52]i325: Registering dependency: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64
[079C:029C][2016-09-12T01:41:52]i301: Applying execute package: Windows81_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[079C:029C][2016-09-12T01:41:57]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[08A4:0680][2016-09-12T01:41:57]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[08A4:0680][2016-09-12T01:41:57]i319: Applied execute package: Windows81_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[08A4:0680][2016-09-12T01:41:57]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[079C:029C][2016-09-12T01:41:57]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[079C:029C][2016-09-12T01:41:57]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[08A4:0680][2016-09-12T01:41:57]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: What is your main issue ?installing VC++ or accessing PHP website ?

Comment: @PramodTiwari accessing PHP web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on following link :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3057448

Cause → Point No. 4

installed update  KB 2919355 and other in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Please install updates for Universal C Runtime in Windows..
[Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226)

After that try to install VC++ again..

Comment: The MSU file generates following error :

[Window Title]
Windows Update Stand-alone Installer

[Main Instruction]
Windows Update Stand-alone Installer

[Content]
This update does not apply to your computer.

Comment: I've already checked using [wmic qfe list] command update : KB2999226 already exists on my system.